Resources for learning Mandarin Chinese: should we include only free material?
I created this Meta question so we can discuss something about it.
I am sure more people will start contributing but I was wondering: should we include only free material (regardless of registrations) or also material that needs to be purchased?
Note: From now on, vote on the answers below. Votes on this question will be considered like any Meta discussion (i.e. vote this up or down if you like it or not, etc.).

Commercial material is now allowed. Please make sure you remember the rules about self-promotion.


I don't think I would delete an answer by someone selling their software, but I might downvote it in some situations.
I think paid material can be a helpful answer, as long as it's clearly described so that people can decide whether they want to pay for it.
If someone asked for a specific tool like something that teaches stroke order using musical notes, then I would welcome anyone who is selling such a tool to post an answer. (I made that up, by the way. I have no idea if such a thing exists or would be useful.)
On the other hand, if someone asks for something more general like flashcard software, then I'd probably downvote an answer that was just a link to some paid software with no description of its advantages over the free options.
Of course, I might delete the post for other reasons. If the person posts links to their software when it's irrelevant to the question, then that smells like spam to me.

Your answer well replies to a common question, but I was asking for the CW I created... :D

Both free and commercial material
Vote this answer up if you agree.
Vote this answer down if you do not agree.

Only free material
Vote this answer up if you agree.
Vote this answer down if you do not agree.
